# Anuglar2 - Error cannot find module

Tags: javascript, css, angular, import, webpack

I'm using Angular2 *rc4* Currently I can import a css file with the ExtractTextPlugin. I'm using html-loader without any problems. However, when i try to load the css files, i get  ***Error: Cannot find module "./app.component.css"*** or ***Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings***. How do i fix this? 
app.comonent.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

const template = require('./app.component.html'); 
const sytles = require('./app.component.css'); 

// Components
import {NavComponent} from './nav/nav.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './footer/footer.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: template,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavComponent, FooterComponent],
    styles: [sytles],
    precompile: [NavComponent, FooterComponent]
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "vendor": "./src/vendor",
    "app": "./src/boot"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./dist/[name].bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
          test: /\.html$/,
          loader: 'html'
      },
      {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader")

      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"./dist/vendor.bundle.js"),
new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')

  ]
}
```

Comment: I still get Error: Cannot find module "./app.component.css"

Comment: whats your folder structure look like

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need to put ExtractTextPlugin in webpack plugins config as described in docs?

Comment: @FriOne, yeah i tried that after i posted this. No luck

Comment: templateUrl: 'quest-summary.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['quest-summary.component.css'] 
[take a look at this file](https://github.com/blinfo/angular2-webpack-seed/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js)

Answer (score -1):

is

```
styles:[sytles];
```

supposed to be

```
styles:[styles];,
```

Comment: also it may need to be styleUrls:[styles] but I am not possitive on that, based on how you are importing it.

Comment: No, to both those ideas.

Answer (score -1):

Use **import** instead of **require**, then it will create a separate app.css file for you and for templates you need `angular2-template-loader` and then you don't need to use require on template it will compile for you.

> Note:- when you do import on css then you don't need to add it to component styles you can just use it directly in your html. For example when you use bootstrap you don't want to add it to every style in every component but want to load only one time then you can simply in the app.ts which is entry point `import "bootstrap"` and you can use it everywhere.

### webppack

`{test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ["ts-loader","angular2-template-loader"]}`

### Component

```
templateUrl :"path"
```

Comment: styles: ["path"] // don't use require

Comment: Yeah, i know about urls. I'm trying to do loaders.

Comment: i use only import on my css files and it work fine. and also styleUrls: ['./app.component.css]